# Proximity Monitoring on the iPhone without blacking out the screen?

Tags: iphone, sensors, proximity

I'm able to detect proximity on the iPhone SDK, but the screen blacks out whenever the proximity state is triggered.

is there a way I can prevent the proximity sensor from blacking out the screen, but still monitor a proximity sensor's state?

Thanks!

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051794/prevent-the-ios-proximity-sensor-from-turning-the-screen-black

Answer (score -1):

You could normally override the `-(void)proximityStateChanged:(BOOL)` changed method and do your thing in there, still getting the changed BOOL state.

Comment: There is no such method in the SDK.